# Checking if server has TRACE enabled

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, trace

I'm looking for a way to check if TRACE is enabled on a **remote** server, does anyone know how to do this? Does a built-in library have this functionality?

So far my program uses the WebRequest, URI, and TcpClient Libraries, does one of these have it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the msdn website, it explains

```
using System.web
```

Has TraceContext.IsEnabled

[MSDN Descript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.tracecontext.isenabled.aspx)

Comment: this would be really great if you added a link and were more careful with your code syntax.  Do that and I'll +1 it.

Comment: Here's the link ;).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.tracecontext.isenabled.aspx

Comment: I believe that function checks if it's enabled on the current machine. I would like to check a machine by supplying an IP address.

Comment: You probably want to add that detail to your question